# Implement multi-column sorting in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, sorting, cocoa, nstableview

I want my NSTableView(s) to allow users to select multiple columns for sorting. I have the default sorting behavior working just fine, but I want the user to be able to click on a primary column header to establish the primary sort order, and then Shift, Option, or Command click on a secondary column header(s) to define sub-sorting.

This seems like a no-brainer, and I would have sworn that I've seen scores of apps that implement this, but hours of searching and reading Apple's documentation has found me no closer to a solution.

I suspect a solution can be implemented using the table delegate method `-tableView:didClickTableColumn:` (and possibly `-tableView:mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn:`). My idea is to catch this message, examine the `currentEvent` and, if the appropriate modifier key is being held down, undo the effects of the last `-tableView:sortDescriptorsDidChange:` message and reorder the sort descriptors into the desired order.

I also want the column header sort indicators to draw accordingly. I suspect that I'll need to do something about `NSTableHeaderCell`'s `-drawSortIndicatorWithFrame:inView:ascending:priority:` method. What perplexes me about that one is I can find no place where the sort indicator state for a column is maintained (or at least accessible using the standard APIs). So I guess I'll have to subclass `NSTableColumn` or `NSTableHeaderCell` and provide my own state. The other thing that confuses me is that the header draw method clearly seems to support a "priority" parameter for multi-key sorting, but I can find nothing in the table column or view classes that let you specify this.

Anyway, if anyone has experience doing this I'd appreciate any feedback, suggestions, techniques, known pitfalls, etc. that you might have. (sample code would not go unappreciated)

Comment: Default sorting IS multi-column sorting. The `sortDescriptors` property of `NSTableView` is an array. Click on column B, click on column A, the table is sorted by A and B.

Comment: See, I just _knew_ this was a no-brainer (LOL)! I wonder why this isn't documented anywhere?